# Grid row to fill available content of page

Tags: html, css, grid, grid-layout, fill

I have five rows in a grid layout.
There is a header row at the top.
I want the content row to fill everything it can of the available space.
I want the footer row to be at the bottom.
Between the header, content and footer rows I have two rows which just adds height spacing at 15px.

Here is HTML-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <div class="headerRow">
            <div>Title</div>
            <div>Fill</div>
            <div>Image</div>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
    
        <div>
             content
        </div>

        <div style="height: 15px"></div>

        <div class="footerRow">
            <div>foo</div>
            <div>bar</div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS-code:

```
.body {
    margin: 15px;
    background: lime;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto auto;
}

.headerRow {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

.footerRow {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I got my "headerRow" to show three columns with the middle column to fill every available space with this line in the CSS:
`grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;`
So I tried this line in the `.body`-block in my CSS:
`grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto auto;`
But that didn't work :'(

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 15px;
  background: lime;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.headerRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  justify-items: center;
}

.footerRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <div class="container">
    <head>
      <title>App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
      <div class="headerRow">
        <div>Title</div>
        <div>Fill</div>
        <div>Image</div>
      </div>

      <div>
           content
      </div>

      <div class="footerRow">
        <div>foo</div>
        <div>bar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use hr tag for adding space instead of another rows. Also if you want to make the three columns inside headerRow, Try adding float : left or adding columns from bootstrap would solve your problem.

Comment: I tried the `<hr>` tag but I don't see how it is supposed to work.
I also tried the `float: left;` in my CSS:headerRow block. But It didn't work.
Unfortunately I'm a beginner using HTML and CSS so I don't understand your suggestions with "bootstrap". What is that?

Answer (score 0):

I have some follow up questions after trying @Nikola Pavicevic solution:

**Question 1:**
In the `html, body` CSS-block the `height: 100%` seems to do the trick for me.
But it makes the page in my web browser to have a vertical scrollbar.
This scrollbar seems to be needed to show the "footer"-row.
Is there anyway to decrease the height of the content row so the header row and footer row is always displayed?

**Question 2:**
The "content-row" seems to not fill all space available in the page.
I can see this by putting a background in the "content-row".
Is there a way to make sure the "content-row" fills all available space?
But keeps the "header-row" and "footer-row" visible.

**Updated HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <div class="container">

    <head>
      <title>App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">
      <div class="headerRow">
        <div>Title</div>
        <div>Fill</div>
        <div>Image</div>
      </div>

      <div class="spacerRow"></div>

      <div class="contentRow">
        content
      </div>

      <div class="spacerRow"></div>

      <div class="footerRow">
        <div>foo</div>
        <div>bar</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Updated CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 15px;
  background: lime;
  display: grid;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.headerRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  justify-items: center;
}

.footerRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.spacerRow {
  height: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.contentRow {
  background-color: purple;
}
```